# Laravel and routing

Tags: laravel, routes

i have a larvel 8 project with other package and route and configured my route like this:

```
            Route::group(['prefix' => config('site.route_prefix', 'site'), 'middleware' => config('site.route.middleware', 'web')], function () {
                Route::get('/post/search/{q?}', [SearchController::class, 'search'])->name('site.search.query');
                ...
```

like this my search route not working, and the search method isnot handled.If i added some text to the route like this, then it work:

```
                Route::group(['prefix' => config('site.route_prefix', 'site'), 'middleware' => config('site.route.middleware', 'web')], function () {
                Route::get('/fdgfgfdgfdg/post/search/{q?}', [SearchController::class, 'search'])->name('site.search.query');
```

my question is where this behavior come from ?

Comment: You put this in your route group: `'prefix' => config('site.route_prefix', 'site')`. What do you think it will do?

Comment: i have update the question, the request is also preced with the prefix itisnt the problem, thanks for your note